# JDBC connection to Shark Server hangs

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hive, shark-sql

I am using following configuration for my shark cluster

- Scala 2.10.3
- Spark 0.9.0
- Hive 0.12.0-chd5.0.2
- Shark 0.9.0

Spark and Hive are configured via Cloudera manager (CDH 5.0.2)

I am following this tutorial to connect to shark server:
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/HiveClient

I start shark server as follows:`./shark --service sharkserver 9956`

I am able to connect to hive server using code in above mentioned tutorial.
But when i try to connect to shark server it hung at this line

`Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:hive://localhost:9956/default", "", "");`

It does not give any error or exception, just program stuck at that line.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve this problem by running server in sudo mode.
In default mode shark server  was unable to write a file because of permission denied error.